# Display new page after clicking ng-click with input values in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, angularjs-ng-click, ngroute

I want to display the object(input values) printed on my view page, i have tried Route but something is missing, since i am beginner in AngularJS, can anyone sort it out ?
My code

index.html

```
<head>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>   

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="inputCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="viewCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5dE8CBcchExh4PvnvAJ4?p=preview